# Using SimpleTemplate in Bottle

Tags: template-engine, bottle

I'm new in Frameworks like Bottle and working through the Documentation/Tutorial.
Now I got a Problem with the Template-Engine:

I have a file called `index.tpl` in my folder `views`. (it's plain html) 
When I use the following Code, it works to display my html:

```
from bottle import Bottle, SimpleTemplate, run, template

app = Bottle()

@app.get('/')
def index():
    return template('index')

run(app, debug=True)
```

Now I want to implement this engine in my project and dont want to use `template()` 
I want to use it as it stands in the documentation, like:

```
tpl = SimpleTemplate('index')

@app.get('/')
def index():
    return tpl.render()
```

But if I do so, the Browser shows me just a white page with the word

> index

written, instead of loading the template. 
In the documentation, there is no further information on how I use this OO approach.
I just couldn't figure out why this happens and how I have to do it right...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a nice, simple solution in the spirit of your original question:

```python
tpl = SimpleTemplate(name='views/index.tpl')  # note the change here

@app.get('/')
def index():
    return tpl.render()
```

Comment: Happy to help.  (Hindsight makes everything look obvious. :)  If the answer solved your problem, please consider marking it accepted.  Thanks!